# Serverpod project failed to deploy with Terraform and AWS

Tags: flutter, dart, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, serverpod

I'm trying to use Serverpod as a full-stack solution in my side project. Locally, everything works without any problems. Unfortunately, I have problems with deploying the app on AWS with Terraform. I try to do it based on Serverpod documentation with step-by-step instructions on how it should be done. I get a problem with launching the EC2 instance when I call

```
terraform apply
```

I see:

```
aws_autoscaling_group.serverpod: Creating...
╷
│ Error: waiting for Auto Scaling Group (terraform-XXXXXXXXX) capacity satisfied: 1 error occurred:
│   * Scaling activity (XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX): Failed: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. Launching EC2 instance failed.
│
│
│
│   with aws_autoscaling_group.serverpod,
│   on instances.tf line 38, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "serverpod":
│   38: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "serverpod" {
│
```

I tried to launch the app in the eu-north-1 region using ami-0b4ab8a966e0c2b21 AMI.
Do you have any suggestion how can I address this problem?